# how to get the md5sum from a bootable CD/DVD?

Tags: iso, dvd, hashsum

AccuHash is a program that can get an md5sum from CD/DVD and without creating an ISO from, but it is a program only running in Windows. I looked around the web for how to do it and there is no reliable method to with Linux, so I want to ask any Linux program like AccuHash? Because my harddisk is pretty full that I couldn't make an ISO any more.

Answer (score 0):

> AccuHash is a program that can get an md5sum from CD/DVD and without creating an ISO from

I assume that you are looking for the md5sum of the files INSIDE of the iso, but not of the ISO itself. Anyways, you can easily do this using the `md5sum` command.

**Usage**

For a single file:
`md5sum filename`

For a directory, and all files folders inside it (i.e. recursive): `find -exec md5sum "{}" \;`